# windows remote desktop not rendering

Tags: windows, screenshot, remote-desktop

I run a windows-app on a remote desktop. It actually has an IE browser inside and I call the Screenshots api sometimes.

When a session is connected to the remote desktop, screenshots are successful and a picture is captured about what is really in the browser. But when no session is connected, a picture with black color is captured. I guess rendering is stopped at this time.

Is there any way to let it render even though no session is connected?

Answer (score 0):

Workround: [use tscon](https://superuser.com/questions/355935/how-can-i-restore-a-remote-desktop-session-to-the-local-console) to move disconnected RDP session to local console. This enables rendering again.